# Flash animation embedded in c# form ignores given size

Tags: c#, flash

I have a simple C# program that, when a user clicks on a button, opens a new frame with an activex flash object embedded in it. The code I use to open it is the following :

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f = new Form();
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash swf = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(swf)).BeginInit();
        f.SuspendLayout();

        swf.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        swf.Enabled = true;
        swf.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, -1);
        swf.Name = "axShockwaveFlash1";
        swf.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axShockwaveFlash1.OcxState")));
        swf.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
        swf.TabIndex = 0;


        f.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        f.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        f.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
        f.Controls.Add(swf);
        f.Name = "Form1";
        f.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"))); ;
        f.Text = "lol";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(swf)).EndInit();
        f.ResumeLayout(false);

        swf.LoadMovie(0, "http://web2.flashgames.it/giochi/puzzle/kaleid/game.swf");
        swf.DisableLocalSecurity();
        f.Show();
    }
```

The test program has been run by several user, without any problem, except for one, that sees this:

[image: What the user sees]

I don't think that the problem is in the application itself, but in the flash player. So, the question is, what am I missing? Are there flash settings that force the window to have the default size?

Comment: Can you provide details as to the differences between the users setup?

Comment: Every user that tested it had the latest stable flash player and shockwave player installed. As for OS, the only user that had problems was running windows 7 ( as soon as I can talk to him, I'll tell you more about his configuration). The others had win7 32bit, win7 64bit or winxp .

Comment: Ok. The system where the program isn't working is Win 7 Home Premium 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that user is running Windows at 120dpi, and WinForms is automatically making your form larger to accommodate. (You're explicitly setting AutoScaleMode on your form, i.e., explicitly telling it to make the form larger in higher-dpi modes.) It looks like the form is about 33% larger than the SWF, which is about right for 96 vs. 120 dpi.

But since you're hard-coding the control's size at 800x600, and not setting AutoScaleMode on it, it's exactly 800x600, i.e., smaller than the form.

To make them the same size, either set AutoScaleMode on `swf` as well, or, better yet, don't duplicate the size -- remove Anchor and Size from `swf`, and set `swf.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;` instead.

Then set windows to 120dpi and run, and see if the Flash app works correctly if it's not at 800x600 pixels. If not, you'll want to disable auto-scaling by changing your form's AutoScaleMode to None.

Comment: I had to work a little on this one. In the end, the solution was to add the swf.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; leaving everything else as it is above. Thank you!